# Zoom animation for Mozilla Firefox or other browsers except Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I gave zoom animation for image in skdslider. In Chrome is everything perfect but in Mozilla having problem the images are zoom after one interval that is 3 images after zoom effect is not working in Mozilla.
I also tried -moz animaton for it, but nothing happen. If you know jQuery for it then also good.

```
   @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    to {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    }
}


@-moz-keyframes zoom {
   from {
        -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
   }
   to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
   }
}



.skdslider ul.slides li img {

-webkit-animation: zoom 15s infinite;
-ms-animation: zoom 15s infinite;
animation: zoom 15s infinite;

}
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code to help others find a fix for you?

Comment: Presently voting to close as not containing enough information, but if it is put on hold, it can be taken off hold if it is edited.

Comment: check the code please..

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. It works in firefox and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/fd6f1dhg/

Comment: but in firefox there is no zoom effect after  3 images..means that zoom effect is not working continously..

Comment: if u know jquery for it.its also good.i will use it instead of css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand in the comments section, you need that animation will loop to infinite. Add this keyword to your syntax:

http://jsfiddle.net/fd6f1dhg/1/

```
-webkit-animation: zoom 15s infinite;
-ms-animation: zoom 15s infinite;
animation: zoom 15s infinite; /* for firefox, doesn't needs -moz prefix*/
```

Comment: yeaa..its working..but again got little bit problem, after 3 images when 1st image is going to start it stuck for 1 or 1.5 sec, after that zoom is working well..

Comment: Please, provide a working example to view your problem. All that we can answer here is pure speculation. Read this to see the rules in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A working example is not a link to your project. Note that most users here are in job and can't visit different websites. Stackoverflow provide a snippet interface and you can attach links to jsfiddle.net with a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm here till almost next year ;)

Comment: I think the problem is in the restart of the list with the plugin. I don't know how to fix it. Maybe you need to research something deeply

Comment: I will pay attention to this question if you update with some news because it's possible that I can help you in the future

Comment: there is any jquery code to do this zoom effect instead of css??

Comment: jQuery have a method called `animate()` that allows you to animate css properties in an element. In this case, you only need to animate the efect of scale. Concept is simple: `$('.photo').animate({ 'scale': '1.5'}, 3000)` where 3000 is the miliseconds of duration for the animation

Comment: no problem, lets try because css giving problem thats why. I will tell you after using jquery for it.

Comment: Did you need the plugin of the gallery or it's only for animate frames?

Comment: Jus..need..one by one images to be..zoom..continusly

Comment: Then there is a simple solution with jQuery. Give me a piece of time and I will make you a snippet example, if nobody have a solution with css.

Comment: I am making a simple gallery with your requirements. Is basic and not tested but it works fine (note that I make it in 10 minutes): https://jsfiddle.net/w14L67qw/

Comment: Yes man. Zoom is working. I include external resource, see it

Comment: 100*100 number is still same..i mean if zoom effect is there..so this numbers will also be zoom because its on image...but still same

Comment: 100x100 is the text inside the image, not the zoom effect. I update the fiddle without that text: https://jsfiddle.net/w14L67qw/1/

Comment: Zoom is in the line that `animate()` has `transition: scale()`

Comment: yes..but still not working..and only one and two image is working for slider without zoom

Comment: I don't know what are you seeing, but in my PC it works (Mac + Firefox). It makes an animation with opacity and scale. It's true, only work the two first images, but the idea is that. I can improve the code so much, but I haven't time right now, maybe in an hour or more.

Comment: m using chrome..its directly showing larg image..instead of coming slowly to zoom..image...may be have problem with chrome

Comment: Yes, I don't know what's the problem. the library used is working on chrome fine http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/ but I don't know what happens